# Generative AI example on offline mode

Tags: nlp, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-2

I would like to develop a script in Python (or other) that allows you to use a free AI (like GPT-2 for example) to answer any question.

Preferably I'd like it to be a pre-trained model that works in offline mode.

Would you have a suggestion please?

Answer (score 2):

Hugging Face has a [leaderboard](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard) of many open LLM models, which you can filter according to various features (such as model size: the big ones are going to need some serious hardware to run).  That's probably the first place I'd look.